# Meter newtons revolutions / second is not compatible with Watts

Tags: units

When I do

```
rotation =Quantity[50.7, (("Radians")/("Seconds"))]
Torque = Quantity[15369, "Meters" "Newtons"]
PuissanceMoteur = Torque rotation
UnitConvert[PuissanceMoteur, "Watts"]
```

I get the error:
    Quantity::compat: (Meters Newtons Revolutions)/(Seconds) and Watts are 
    incompatible units

Any explanation ?

Rgrds,

==========

Updating a little bit on another inconsistency:

When I do

```
UnitConvert[rotation, "revolutions"]*rayons[[4]] 2 \[Pi] Quantity[1, "Millimeters"]/Quantity[1, "Revolutions"]
```

I get:

```
Quantity[33943.5, ("Millimeters" "Revolutions")/("Seconds")]
```

However if I declare:

```
revs = Quantity[1, "Revolutions"]
```

and then do:

```
UnitConvert[rotation, "revolutions"]*rayons[[4]] 2 \[Pi] Quantity[1, "Millimeters"]/revs
```

I get:

```
Quantity[1, "Revolutions"]

Quantity[33943.5, ("Millimeters")/("Seconds")]
```

This is wrong as I do exactly the same thing here ?

Comment: Just found another inconsistency:

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `"Radians"` is not interpreted as dimensionless by default:

`UnitConvert[PuissanceMoteur, "Watts*Radians"]`

`779208.rad W`